# save and fetch on firebase in angular is not working

Tags: javascript, html, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Why my movie component is not updating after fetching the data. Also not saving the data if I have added a new movie or made changes in existing movies.

It is just saving and fetching the data which is written in movie.service.ts file. Also the fetched data is not rendering on the movie component.

Data-storage.service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { MovieService } from '../movies/movies.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Movie } from '../movies/movie.model';
import { Observable} from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
// import 'rxjs/Rx';
// import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataStorageService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient,
    private movieService: MovieService,) { }

  storeMovies(): Observable<any> {
    const req = new HttpRequest('PUT', 'https://moviepedia-4211a.firebaseio.com/movies.json', this.movieService.getMovies(), {reportProgress: true});
    return this.httpClient.request(req);
  }

  getMovies() {
    this.httpClient.get<Movie[]>('https://moviepedia-4211a.firebaseio.com/movies.json', {
      observe: 'body',
      responseType: 'json'
    })
      .pipe(map(
        (movies) => {
          console.log(movies);
          return movies;
        }
      ))
      .subscribe(
        (movies: Movie[]) => {
          this.movieService.setMovies(movies);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

movie.service.ts :

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';
import { Movie } from './movie.model';

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    moviesChanged = new Subject<Movie[]>();

    private movies: Movie[] = [
        new Movie(
            'Movie test', 'Movie details', 'https://s18672.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Movie-300x200.jpg'
        ),
        new Movie(
            'Movie test 2', 'Movie details 2', 'https://s18672.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Movie-300x200.jpg'
        ),
        new Movie(
            'Movie test 2', 'Movie details 3', 'https://s18672.pcdn.co/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Movie-300x200.jpg'
        )
    ];

    constructor(){}

    getMovie(index: number) {
        return this.movies[index];
    }

    getMovies() {
        return this.movies.slice();
    }

    addMovie(movie: Movie) {
        this.movies.push(movie);
        this.moviesChanged.next(this.movies.slice());
    }
    
    updateMovie(index: number, newMovie: Movie) {
        this.movies[index] = newMovie;
        this.moviesChanged.next(this.movies.slice());
    }

    deleteMovie(index: number) {
        this.movies.splice(index, 1);
        this.moviesChanged.next(this.movies.slice());
    }

    setMovies(movies: Movie[]) {
        this.movies = movies;
        this.moviesChanged.next(this.movies.slice());
    }
}
```

movie.model.ts

```js
export class Movie {
    public name: string;
    public description: string;
    public imagePath: string;
  
    constructor(name: string, description: string, imagePath: string) {
      this.name = name;
      this.description = description;
      this.imagePath = imagePath;
    }
  }
```

movie.component :

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Output, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Movie } from '../movie.model'
import { MovieService } from '../movies.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-movie-list',
  templateUrl: './movie-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./movie-list.component.css']
})
export class MovieListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  subscription: Subscription;
  
  movies: Movie[] = [];

  constructor(private movieService: MovieService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.movieService.moviesChanged
    .subscribe(
      (movies: Movie[]) => {
        this.movies = movies;
      }
    );
  this.movies = this.movieService.getMovies();
  }

  onNewMovie() {
    this.router.navigate(['new'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

What can I do save and fetch data which will render on page.

Comment: Have you checked if your data returns from server?
in browser network tool.

Comment: Also, could you please add movie component, because it's difficult to understand why it's not being rendered without seeing the component

Comment: @AmirArbabian Yes, it is showing there. But when I update the movies list, the new list is not saved or fetched.

Comment: @AmirArbabian Added the component.

Comment: @face can you please disable any adblocker if exist. Sometimes it blocks firebase requests!

Comment: @HaidarZeineddine In console I can see data is saved and fetched but it is not updating on the movie component.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your `PUT` request is that the url you used expects `json` but you are sending `Movie` object. you should send and receive `json` to this url.

wish it helps ...

Comment: But my data is storing as shown in console and browser network took.

Comment: The data which is stored or fetched is that present in the movie.service.ts